# Getting an Issue in appending the value of one string to another string in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I am trying to append the value of a string in another string variable and then display that string variable in the detailtextlabel of tableview.but my query is my string is not getting appended properly.What may be the issue.This is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    repeatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    repeatArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"week"];

    if (sun && mon && tue && wed && thu && fri && sat) 
    {
        app.repeat =@"Every day";
    }
    else if (mon && tue && wed && thu && fri && !sat && !sun)
    {
        app.repeat = @"Every Week days";
    }
    else if (sat && sun && !mon && !tue && !wed && !thu && !fri)
    {
        app.repeat = @"Every Weekends";
    } 
    else if (sun || mon || tue || wed|| thu || fri || sat)
    {
        if (sun) 
        {
            app.repeat = @"Every Sunday";
            NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
        }
        if (mon)
        {
            app.repeat= @"Every Monday";
            NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
        }
        if(tue)
        {
            app.repeat = @"Every Tuesday";
            NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);        
        }
        if(wed)
        {
            app.repeat = @"Every Wednesday";
            NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
        }
        if(thu)
        {
            app.repeat = @"Every Thursday";
            NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);        
        }
        if(fri) 
        {
            app.repeat = @"Every Friday";
            NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
        }
        if(sat)
        {
            app.repeat = @"Every Saturday";
            NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
        }
    }
}
```

All this is working is fine .But I select mon and tue then only every Tuesday is displayed.Instead "Every Mon,Tue " displayed.

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: How do you want it? **"Every Monday and Every Tuesday"**?

Comment: @EmptyStack No when Monday and Tuesday is selected i want "Every Mo,Tue"

Comment: Please format your questions better in future. Your code is very hard to read. I have formatted it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You're not appending a string, you're simply setting `repeat` to a new string. Maybe you want this?

```
app.repeat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", app.repeat, @"Every Friday"];
```

Or even simpler, this?

```
app.repeat = [app.repeat stringByAppendingString:@"Every Friday"];
```

Also, you have a leak; you alloc an array and then you lose reference to it by assigning to it the returned object from `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"week"]`.

EDIT: Well, your original code was spaghetti - and my code won't help - but here's what you could do (though I would never do this myself):

```
BOOL alreadyModified = NO;
if (sun) 
{
    app.repeat = @"Every Sunday";
    alreadyModified = YES;
    NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
}
if (mon)
{
    if (alreadyModified)
    {
        app.repeat = [app.repeat stringByAppendingString:@", Monday"];
    }
    else
    {
        app.repeat= @"Every Monday";
        alreadyModified = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
}
if(tue)
{
    if (alreadyModified)
    {
        app.repeat = [app.repeat stringByAppendingString:@", Tuesday"];
    }
    else
    {
        app.repeat= @"Every Tuesday";
        alreadyModified = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);        
}
if(wed)
{
    if (alreadyModified)
    {
        app.repeat = [app.repeat stringByAppendingString:@", Wednesday"];
    }
    else
    {
        app.repeat= @"Every Wednesday";
        alreadyModified = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
}
if(thu)
{
    if (alreadyModified)
    {
        app.repeat = [app.repeat stringByAppendingString:@", Thursday"];
    }
    else
    {
        app.repeat= @"Every Thursday";
        alreadyModified = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);        
}
if(fri) 
{
    if (alreadyModified)
    {
        app.repeat = [app.repeat stringByAppendingString:@", Friday"];
    }
    else
    {
        app.repeat= @"Every Friday";
        alreadyModified = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
}
if(sat)
{
    if (alreadyModified)
    {
        app.repeat = [app.repeat stringByAppendingString:@", Saturday"];
    }
    else
    {
        app.repeat= @"Every Saturday";
        alreadyModified = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"weekday:%@",app.repeat);
}
```

Comment: Alan Zeino but when i select monday and tuesday,@"Every Mon,Tue" should be displayed

Comment: I know the answer you desire but I don't think I should spoon-feed you this. Make a string with @"Every " and then append the selected days, separating with a comma each time. You'll have to refactor the above code anyway.

Comment: Eh, I wrote a solution for you. Check the above. It's pretty average, but hopefully you'll see what you should be doing to check if the string is new or one to be appended upon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you append strings. You just create a new string. See this methods:

- [– stringByAppendingFormat:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingFormat%3a)
- [– stringByAppendingString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Your continually resetting your repeat String to a new value without appending anything on to it.

Try this:

```
repeat = [repeat stringByAppendingString:@"Every Tuesday"];
```

You will have to edit what way you concatenate the Strings yourself for your desired final output, the above would give "Every MondayEvery Tuesday" for example.

Comment: Any chance of a comment on why my answer was down voted twice? Not much point in down voting it without pointing out why so both I and anyone reading it can learn from it.